# I want to add people into groups with eloquent laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables **Users** and **Groups**, i want to add users into groups with **eloquent relationship**. 
mysql tables:

**Groups** table:

```
      id
      name
      user_id
```

**Users** table:

```
      id
      name
      email
      password
```

**Group.php** model has:

```
    public function user()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\User');
        }
```

**User.php** model has:

```
    public function group()
       {
           return $this->belongsTo('App\Group');
       }
```

**GroupController.php**

```
    public function store(Request $request)
     {
       $request->validate([
       'name'=>'required|string',
       'user_id' => 'required',

     ]);
       $group = new Group([
       'name' => $request->get('name'),
       'user_id'=> $request->get('user_id')
     ]);
     $group->save();

     return redirect('/groups')->with('success', 'Group has been added');
     }
```

**create.blade.php** view

```
    <div class="form-group">
            <select name="user_id[]"  class="form-control" multiple>
                @foreach ($users as $user)
                <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
     </div>
```

The error is "**Array to string conversion**"
If i add a "dd($group)" before save() at TeamController i get the user_ids [dd results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSSai.png) but when it tries to $group->save(); i get the error, any help ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you tried to do is not possible by your table structure. You need to change your table structure,

one Group - many User,

So, Your table structure should be,

**Group**

```
  id
  name
```

**User**

```
  id
  name
  email
  password
  group_id
```

And your relation definition should be,

**Group model**

```
  public function users()
   {
      return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'group_id');
   }
```

**User model**

```
   public function group()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Group', 'group_id');
    }
```

And Lastly,

```
public function store(Request $request)
 {
   $request->validate([
   'name'=>'required|string',
   'user_id' => 'required|array',

 ]);
 $group = new Group([
   'name' => $request->get('name'),
 ]);
 $group->save();
  foreach($request->get('user_id') as $id)
  {
    $user = App\User::findOrFail($id);
    $user->group_id = $group->id
    $user->save();
  }

   return redirect('/groups')->with('success', 'Group has been added');
 }
```

Comment: `$user_id` is not defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot  for your complete answer

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop to save user to group.

```
foreach($request->user_id as $user_id)
     $group = new Group([
         'name' => $request->get('name'),
         'user_id'=> $user_id
     ]);
     $group->save();
)
```

Comment: hey, i get "Undefined variable: user_id"

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

as other comments stated you should loop over them.
Shouldn't you have the group_id on the user model tho?
That way you have group name unique and and can ad a user to a group or if you want a user to belong to many groups create a pivot table for it.

## Groups table:

```
id
name
```

## Users table:

```
id
name
email
password
group_id
```

edit:
as stated by the other guys you will have to loop over them. the variable  `$request->get('user_id')` contains the array of all the users selected in your  tag. you want to loop over that. this will create duplicated names in your group table tho.

```
foreach ($request->get('user_id') as $userid){
    $group = new Group();
    $group->name = $request->get('name');
    $group->user_id = $userid;
    $group->save();
}
```

Comment: Yes thats the correct way , parent child , but how i will go then to group view and multiselect the users? to add them on the group

Comment: see my example in the edit, hope that makes it clear

Comment: Thanks for your help